# Get number of grid-cell required to display a component in CSS

Tags: css, css-grid

I am building a css grid display with fixed number of column 2 and unknown number of rows.
I'd use something like:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-column: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 12rem;
}

.component {
  grid-row: span 2; 
}
```

Inside my container I would display a list `C[]` of components C whose width is known and the same for all components, let's call it W
However, the height of my components is different for each (it depends on text inside components, length of the data it should display, how it should display it...). We'll call H(C) the height of each component.

I am looking for a way to change for long components the span they should have to display its content: i.e: What is the value of span `vSpan` so that

```
vSpan * 12rem >= H(C) > (vSpan -1) * 12rem
```

- I already tried using a display flex, but I could not find a way to stack blocks below each other